# Unable to link Crypto++ Speck algorithm due to undefined references

Tags: c++, linker-errors, crypto++

I'm trying to utilize Crypto++'s Simon and Speck implementations for a research project, but I currently cannot compile and link the example code provided on its wiki page.

Following the instructions from the Crypto++ wiki, I was able to build the library and run all of their test suites to completion. I have also been able to run example AES code from the same wiki. The compilation errors only come when I try to invoke Simon or Speck.

To compile and link the file I am using `g++ speck_test.cpp -lcryptopp`.

Here is the program provided on the Crypto++ Speck wiki. I added include statements and scope resolutions where I believed necessary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "cryptopp/speck.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    CryptoPP::SPECK128::Encryption speck;

    std::cout << "StaticAlgorithmName: " << speck.StaticAlgorithmName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "AlgorithmName (unkeyed): " << speck.AlgorithmName() << std::endl;

    CryptoPP::byte key[CryptoPP::SPECK128::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH] = {};
    speck.SetKey(key, sizeof(key));

    std::cout << "AlgorithmName (keyed): " << speck.AlgorithmName() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output of this program according to the wiki is

```
StaticAlgorithmName: SPECK-128
AlgorithmName (unkeyed): SPECK-128
AlgorithmName (keyed): SPECK-128(128)
```

however, I am receiving the following error from the compiler:

```
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o: In function `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::Base()':
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC5Ev]+0x2c): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base'
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC5Ev]+0x3a): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base'
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC5Ev]+0x49): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o: In function `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::~Base()':
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseD5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base'
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseD5Ev]+0x1d): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseD5Ev]+0x2c): more undefined references to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base' follow
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o: In function `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::Enc()':
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC5Ev]+0x1b): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc'
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC5Ev]+0x29): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc'
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC5Ev]+0x38): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o: In function `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::~Enc()':
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncD5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc'
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncD5Ev]+0x1d): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncD2Ev[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncD5Ev]+0x2c): more undefined references to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc' follow
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::AlgorithmProvider[abi:cxx11]() const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE]+0x40): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE]+0xe0): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE]+0x128): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::AlgorithmProvider[abi:cxx11]() const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE]+0x130): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEE]+0x160): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE]+0x28): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::AlgorithmProvider[abi:cxx11]() const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE]+0x30): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE]+0x38): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE]+0x40): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE]+0xd8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::UncheckedSetKey(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, CryptoPP::NameValuePairs const&)'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE]+0x120): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::AlgorithmProvider[abi:cxx11]() const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE]+0x128): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::ProcessAndXorBlock(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*) const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE[_ZTVN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE]+0x158): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned int) const'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE[_ZTIN8CryptoPP12ClonableImplINS_16BlockCipherFinalILNS_9CipherDirE0ENS_8SPECK1283EncEEES4_EE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o: In function `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base::Base(CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base const&)':
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC2ERKS1_[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC5ERKS1_]+0x41): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base'
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC2ERKS1_[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC5ERKS1_]+0x4f): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base'
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC2ERKS1_[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1284BaseC5ERKS1_]+0x5e): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Base'
/tmp/ccD02cM7.o: In function `CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc::Enc(CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc const&)':
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC2ERKS1_[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC5ERKS1_]+0x26): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc'
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC2ERKS1_[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC5ERKS1_]+0x34): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc'
speck_test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC2ERKS1_[_ZN8CryptoPP8SPECK1283EncC5ERKS1_]+0x43): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SPECK128::Enc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: That looks like every single reference to `cryptopp` is missing.  The crypto++ library is missing - either because you haven't built it correctly before trying to use it or because it isn't located where the compiler can find it (you might need to add a `-L <dir>` to the compiler command.

Answer (score 1):

As dave pointed out, the error was arose from the compiler being unable to find CryptoPP.

To fix this, I had to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable on Ubuntu to include the path to the library. Then, I had to alter my compiler command to compile my file first, then link the library second, i.e.

`g++ -o test.exe speck_test.cpp -L<path-to-cryptopp> -lcryptopp`

rather than

`g++ -L<path-to-cryptopp> -lcryptopp -o test.exe speck_test.cpp`, which was failing.

Comment: You can also use `-l:libcryptopp.a`. That will utilize static linking, and you won't have to dick around with broken Linux paths. Also see the [`ld(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) and the discussion of `:filename`.